# How to undo is_mobile in nested element in bulma?

Tags: html, css, bulma

```
<div class="level is-mobile name_logo">
    <div class="level-left">
        <div class="level-item has-text-centered">
            <p class="heading">Example 1</p>
            <p class="is-size-5 has-text-weight-bold title">Example 2</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

In this example I use is-mobile class do make force classes inside to display in a row. The problem is this is forcing the `<p class="heading">` and `<p class="title">` to be displayed in a row to. Not even using `<br>` tag I am having success to display these two `<p>` in column. Is there anything I can do?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to do something like the Mobile Level example on the Bulma docs? https://bulma.io/documentation/layout/level/#mobile-level

`.level-item` is set to `display:flex`, which makes the level items show in rows.  In the example provided in the Bulma docs, there's an extra `div` wrapping the `.heading` and `.title` elements.  Add that extra div and the text will show on two lines.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.7.4/css/bulma.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="level is-mobile name_logo">
    <div class="level-left">
        <div class="level-item has-text-centered">
          <div>
            <p class="heading">Example 1</p>
            <p class="is-size-5 has-text-weight-bold title">Example 2</p>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```